# Enzymes extracted from diferent tissue, may have diferent $K_m$ values under the same conditions?

Tags: biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics

My laboratory team has been used **succinate dehydrogenase** (1.3.5.1) from *Gallus gallus domesticus* breast (the most meated part of the chicken, where you will obtain nuggets) to determine $K_{m}$ and $V_{max}$ under 3 linearization methods.

But, in [BRENDA](https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.3.5.1#KM%20VALUE%20[mM]) page, I found various values for many organisms, like *Bos taurus*, and they select other tissues like liver tissue.

Why the difference?

PD. Any reference about where to find this values for *Gallus gallus mesticus* will be very appreciated.

EDIT: The reaction consists on dehydrogenating succinate to fumarate, on the tricarborxilic acid cycle. Include the creation of a trans-double bond.

Describing my laboratory practice, we macerate the meat with glass sand, and divide this mixture on 2 kinds: one with methylene blue and trichloroacetic acid (TCA) and one without TCA. Now I know that TCA is a protein precipitant, and methylene blue is an indicator; the less blue, the less succinate. So, with absorbance tests, we can elucidate **[Succinate] vs time plot**, and approximate the ratio $V_{max}/K_m$ from the michaelian equation for substrate concentration decay:
$$S(t)=S_0 e^{-\frac{V_{max}}{K_m}t}$$
Also, i think it will be possible modeling instantaneous velocity with its derivate and make the linealization plots, but i'm not very sure of this.

EDIT2: Thanks for the help with my practice report (I really appreciate it), but I still wanna know if it's possible to have different $K_m$ values on the same enzyme, only changing the tissue for reaction.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add an example of such enzymes from BRENDA?

Comment: Also note that succinate dehydrogenase is a part of a complex and catalyzes many coupled reactions. A simple MM kinetic model won't apply in this case, I believe. Which reaction are you interested in?

Comment: As far as I know Brenda lists experimentally determined values, if they come from different studies/sources the differences are much more likely to be due to that than due to different tissues

Comment: I need experimentally values reported, so data in BRENDA is usefull. But I duno why it will be different values on different tissues. This is not possible, under the same conditions?

Comment: user1136 thank, I didn't know about the protein precipitation effect of TCA. That changes everything, since the Rx have a non-competitive inhibition.

Comment: user1136 In fact, I didn't found different values for $V_{max}$, I found different values only for $K_{m}$ and the ratio. If you know a website or a book where I will found it, can you tell me, please?

Comment: My teacher derived that formule from Michaelis-menten eqn assuming that $K_m >> S_0$ and omitting it at denominator. Then: $$V_0=\frac{Vmax . S_0}{Km} = -\frac{dS_0}{dt}$$ but this is not my question. Maybe I need to open another question for linealization?

Comment: I'd like to do that. That was i'm thinking. But my partners, who have re-coursed enzymology, used another method using an equation that I don't even know. If you are interested, i let you the link to the report, but is in spanish and i can't explain it to you at all. [  https://1drv.ms/w/s!AtNW_8yW8ySxgkGDfKg4KoHaWzbp ] You know, mathematics don't have a language. They are a language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would not expect the same enzyme from different tissues to have different Km values if the enzymes are truly identical.

In addition, you would not expect the Km value to change during purification: the Michaelis constant for the purified enzyme should be the same as that determined with a crude sample.  If this is not true, it might mean that the enzyme has become modified during purification, perhaps by proteolysis (not something you want your examiner to point out or suggest!).

One advantage of the Michaelis constant is that it is independent of enzyme concentration (and so does not depend on the degree of purity).

Having said that, I think it would not be considered too unusual for enzymes isolated from different tissues to have different Km values.

Possible reasons are:

- The assay conditions are not really the same. pH, ionic strength, *temperature* and buffer composition may all affect  Km.  The Michaelis constant determined at pH 7 in 100mM phosphate at 37<sup>o</sup>C may be very different from that determined in 50mM Tris pH 7 and 25<sup>o</sup>C
- Post-translation modification may be important.  The enzyme from one tissue may be phosphorylated, for example. One laboratory may have isolated the modified from, whereas another laboratory may routinely include phosphatase inhibitors.
- Proteases present in the crude tissue preparation may have modified the enzyme.

In the case of succinate dehydrogenase, there are two other important considerations.

- Succinate dehydrogenase is a membrane-bound enzyme (containing a covalently bound flavin) and the method of extraction will be all-important, and a key area to examine is whether extraction conditions may account for the difference in Km.
- Finally, and this one is important I think.  SDH *is a two-substrate enzyme* and the Km for substrate A *will depend on the concentration of substrate B* ! To determine the 'true' Michaelis constant for a two-substrate enzyme (assuming no substrate inhibition), we must extrapolate to 'infinite' concentrations of the co-substrate. Otherwise we are dealing with *apparent* Km values.

I'll bet the last point is important. Is the problem that at least some of the reported Kms are *apparent* values, ie the concentration of co-substrate is different under the different experimental conditions?

Comment: *One advantage of the Michaelis constant is that it is independent of enzyme concentration (and so does not depend on the degree of purity).*   This is strictly true in the limit of dilute enzyme concentrations and saturating substrate concentrations, $[S]_{tot} >>[E]_{tot}$ which is usually the case but not necessarily feasible at all stages of purification. If Km is determined in subsaturating conditions (or concentrations that cause protein aggregation) it will apparently change over the purification.

Comment: "... which is usually the case but not necessarily feasible at all stages of purification" ?? In my experience,  [S]o will always exceed [E]o at all stages of purification This is one of the simplifying assumptions of the steady-state approximation, under which Km is usually defined. Can you give an example where this is not feasible during purification. (ii)  "If Km is determined in subsaturating conditions" Subsaturating concs of what? Of [S]o ?  This _has_ to be the case if a rate is determined at sub-Km concentrations.  Of [E]o?? But the usual assumption is that Eo << So (always)

Comment: *Can you give an example where this is not feasible during purification.*  If the substrate has low solubilities (for example, gualylates, methyxanthines) then at high enzyme activities the maximum feasible substrate concentration can be subsaturating. If the enzyme has a high specific activity, for example superoxide dismutase, then obtaining saturating substrate concentrations can also be difficult. There are some obvious technical solutions to these problems but, if they aren't implemented correctly, the *apparent* Km will change over the purification.

Comment: If the substrate has a low solubility it may be impossible to determine the Michaelis constant at _all_ stages of purification if the highest conc of substrate that can be obtained in the assay is way below Km. But this _does not mean_ that the Km has changed during purification.  As long as assay conditions differ only in the degree of purity of the enzyme, and as long as the steady-state approximation applies, one would _not_ expect the Michaelis constant to change during purification.  The purified enzyme will be typically diluted to ensure steady-state conditions, for example

Comment: i didn't say Km *actually* changed I said it can *apparently* change over a purification.

Comment: A Km _can_ change over the course of  a purification. Solubilization of a membrane-bound enzyme _could_ change the Km, as could proteolysis. I have made this point.  This is an undesirable (but perhaps unavoidable) outcome as the enzyme is no longer in the 'native' state. But if the Km is determined under steady-state conditions there is no problem whatsoever in determining a Km with a crude sample, as Km _is independent of enzyme concentration_ (under SS conditions). This is what allows us to compare.  Most of the early work on enzyme kinetics, for example, was done with impure preparations.